# Updating columns after a new record has been inserted

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I have a table book_assign and when a new record has been inserted, I want to update previous entries for the stud_id and set the column 'status' to become 0.

```
 public function insert() {
    $stud_id = mysql_real_escape_string($this->stud_id);
    $teach_id = mysql_real_escape_string($this->teach_id);
    $book_id = mysql_real_escape_string($this->book_id);
    $status = mysql_real_escape_string($this->status);
    $dates = mysql_real_escape_string($this->dates);
    $rating = mysql_real_escape_string($this->rating);
    $comments = mysql_real_escape_string($this->comments);


    $insert = "Insert into book_assign(stud_id,teach_id, book_id, dates, status, rating, comments)
                values('$stud_id', '$teach_id', '$book_id', '$dates', '1', '$rating', '$comments')";



    $res = mysql_query($insert);
    $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
    return $res;
}
```

This is my code so far, I believe I may have to use a trigger does that have to be done in phpmyadmin?

What I'm also wondering is can this be done using two different queries within this function, I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with two queries. Write this query after your insert :

```
update book_assign set status=0 where stud_id='$stud_id';
```

This can also achieve with [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html). You can set trigger from `phpmyadmin`.

Please dont use `mysql_*`. It is deprecated and removed from PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Also your query is open for sql injection.Please read this : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)